# fibonacci pairs and matplotlib

Tags: python

I created a function, that asks how many fib numbers you would like to see and then returns that many numbers from the sequence.

I am trying to get fib pairs from the list I have created of the numbers. Here is where I am lost.

0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13

The pairs I want look like this.

0,1

1,1

1,2

2,3

3.5

5,8

8,13

I seem to be missing something as my list of fib numbers is blank but still returning the values when called.

See the code below, please explain what I am missing?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fib_nums = [0, 1]
n = 0
num1 = 0
num2 = 1

x_coords = [1,2]
x_count = 3
y_coords = [0,1]
coord_pairs = ()
def fib(n):

    global x_coords
    global x_count

    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 1

    for i in range(n-2):
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c

        fib_nums.append(c)
        y_coords.append(c)
        x_coords.append(x_count)
        x_count = x_count + 1

    return(fib_nums)


for num in fib_nums:

    num1 = num1 + 1
    num2 = num2 + 2
    temp_list = [fib_nums[num1:],fib_nums[num2:]]


n = int(input('How many Fib numbers would you like to see? : '))
fib(n)
print(fib_nums)
print(temp_list)

# plt.scatter(y_coords, x_coords) # .scatter(x,y) <<<----- this is actually how this works
# plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you asking to convert list of fibonacci numbers to pairs of list of fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Could you explain your logic in the question? It would help us make sure your code is doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
fib = [0,1]
n = int(input())
for i in range(2,n):
  fib.append(fib[i-1]+fib[i-2])

pairs = []

for i in range(n-1):
  pairs.append([fib[i],fib[i+1]])

print(pairs)
```

Input:

```
10
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 8], [8, 13], [13, 21], [21, 34]]
```

Plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pairs = np.array(pairs)

plt.scatter(pairs[:,0],pairs[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Plot]

Comment: if so, would you mind explaining it a little bit more as that is exactly what I wanted. thank you for your time

Comment: it says the list index out of range?

Comment: all I can say is this code is absolutely amazing, I just wish I understood it fully. 

for num in range(2,n):
    fib.append(fib[num-1]+fib[num-2])
    print(fib[num-1]+fib[num-2])

Comment: Initially you have only 2 numbers inside list and then you add these two numbers and append it to list i.e fib.append(fib[num-1]+fib[num-2]) and when you want nth fibonacci number, then you need to add n-1 and n-2 th fibonacci numbers. Yes this the whole code.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped. It helps the community at large in recognizing the correct answer.  You can do that by clicking the tick mark next the answer.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common thing to do, I have seen `zip` many times to achieve that :

```
fib_seq = fib(10)
pairs = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(fib_seq, fib_seq[1:])]
```

Explenation:

You have two sequences here: `fib_seq` and `fib_seq[1:]`:

0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...

1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...

`zip` will take first element from each of you sequences and will create a tuple out of them:

[(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), ...]

Comment: `zip` yields tuples anyway, so `list(zip(...))` is a bit simpler.

Comment: As I said above, the one liners are a little bit dificult to follow. i know my code is rudimentary at best but I am very much still on the first few chapters.

Comment: I am sure you can understand that list comprehension like that, although necessary as an end goal, is not my main focus at the moment and would like to see and understand more broken down code. 
thank you for your input anyway (y)